# What is the meaning of the dot in this open() usage in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I understand the following usage of the `open()` function in Perl File I/O?

```
open(FHANDLE, ">" . $file )
```

I tried to find this type of syntax [in the docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) but did not find; please note there is a . (dot) after ">".

All I cannot understand is a use of dot, the rest I know.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an example of the old, two-argument form of `open` (which should be avoided now that three-argument `open` is available).  In Perl, `.` is the append operator.  It combines the two strings into a single string.

The line of code you posted is equivalent to `open(FHANDLE, ">$file" )`, it just uses a different method of combining the `>` and `$file`.

The better way to do it these days would be `open(my $fhandle, '>', $file)`, as shown in the documentation you linked to.

Answer (score 8):

This is the two-argument `open`. The dot `.` is the string concatenation operator in Perl. If `open` is called with two arguments, the second argument contains both the mode and the path.

In your case, it will open the file named in `$file` for writing.

However, for several reasons you should not do this. It's more common to use the three-argument-open, and the lexical filehandles instead of the global GLOB filehandle.

The lexical filehandle makes sure Perl implicitly closes the handel for you as soon as it goes out of scope. Using different args for mode and filename is a security concern, because otherwise a malicious user could smuggle in mode-changes into the filename.

```
open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
```

IN addition to the now lexical filehandle and the separation of the mode and the filename, we also check for errors in this code, which is always a good idea.