# Pointer of a file handle in perl

Tags: perl

Referring  to below lines :

```
 open(FILE, ">" ,$file )
 FILE->autoflush;
 $self->{FILEH} = *FILE;
```

Want to understand what is last two lines doing , the second line outputs whatever FILE has (until the point second line is reached) to the file represented by $file and then stores the reference of FILE ( reference to file handler  represented by *FILE ) into a blessed hash key (here $self is a blessed hash ref). Please let me know if my understanding is correct . Can *FILE be replace with \FILE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it cannot be replaced with `\FILE`.

The `FILE` has different meanings. I'll try to explain each of them per line.

```
open(FILE, ">" ,$file ); # GLOB file handle
FILE->autoflush;         # GLOB gets magically converted to an IO::Handle object
$self->{FILEH} = *FILE;  # accessing the typeglob as a typeglob
```

There are three different things at work here.

When you `open` the filehandle, it's just a GLOB. Essentially that is a filehandle that is global in your program.

In the next line, you call a method on the GLOB filehandle. Perl is smart, and upgrades the filehandle to an IO::Handle object, so it can call the method for you.

In the third line, the typeglob is assigned to a property of your object. In this case, the typeglob itself is a thing that's being assigned. But it's not a reference. This shows how weird typeglobs are, and that this kind of filehandle is confusing and shouldn't be used.

But if you do `\FILE` it's not going to work. Look at this:

```
$ perl -E 'say \STDOUT'
SCALAR(0x2534f58)
$ perl -E 'use strict; say \STDOUT'
Bareword "STDOUT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

If you leave out the `*` Perl thinks your bareword `STDOUT` is a function call, but no function `STDOUT` exists, so it fails. In the first example, without `strict`, the bareword instead gets treated as a string. A reference is taken, and we see a scalar reference.

If you wanted to take the reference of the typeglob, you'd have to do `\*FILE`.

```
$ perl -E 'say \*STDOUT'
GLOB(0x24e3858)
```

However, that could break your program, because your program likely expects *a GLOB*, and **not** a *reference to a GLOB*.

Comment: what's a GLOB file handle ?

Comment: @Vicky please read [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426294/1331451).

Comment: Actually, it's unlikely to break a program. Things that expect handles usually accept ref to IO objects (`*STDOUT{IO}`), globs (`*STDOUT`) and reference to globs (`\*STDOUT`).

Comment: @ikegami better safe than sorry I guess.

Comment: If you want to be safe, you want a ref to glob (`\*STDOUT`), because that's what `open(my $fh, ...)` puts in `$fh`.

Comment: @simbabque, sorry I did not understand this part "lexical filehandles instead of the global GLOB filehandle" . What is lexical file handle and what is GLOB file handle ? sorry I thought there is only just file handle in perl :).

Comment: @Vicky do you know what it means when a variable is lexical?

Comment: @simbabque, yes when it is only available inside current block , in perl it is done by my keyword

Comment: @Vicky exactly. If you use `my $fh` as your file handle, it's the same. It's only available in the current scope and it will be `close`d automatically at the end of that scope. But the glob will not. If you forget to `close`, it's there until the program exits, and because it's a glob it is accessible from every other place in your program.

Comment: So why not just $self->{FILEH}=FILE? What's the difference in FILE and *FILE?

Comment: The FILE in this case is going to be treated as a bareword, so Perl will look it up as a function, which doesn't exist. Useing bareword filehandles only works in places where the syntax allows them.